# Operator Precedence and associativity

Tags: php, php-5.3

I don't inderstand why this instruction will output 5. And how PHP interpreter will execute it.

```
$a = (1 << 0);
$b = (1 << $a);
$c = (1 << $b);

echo ($c || $b) << 2 * $a | $a; //5
```

Comment: Did you read this?  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: The only thing in there not directly readable in the above linked page is that `($c || $b)` => `true` => `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = (1 << 0);     // 1
$b = (1 << $a);    // doesnt matter, not used
$c = (1 << $b);    // doesnt matter, not used

echo ($c || $b) << 2 * $a | $a; //5
// ($c || $b) will return true, meaning 1
// so you can rewrite it as
echo 1 << 2 * $a | $a
// $a = 1, so:
echo 1 << 2 * 1 | 1
// or:
echo 1 << 2 | 1
// ->
echo 4 | 1 // = 5
```

Comment: thx, but there is another instruction that i can't understand

Comment: i'm starting to think you don't understand the | operator completly. i'll try to explain. you are doing (1 | 2). in binary code 1 is '001' and 2 in binary is: '010', when you use the | each bit is compared and when one of the bit is 1 (or both) it will result in 1. meaning (001 | 010) = 011 which is the binary value for 3 in decimal. Hope this makes any sense to you.

Comment: Thx @Elpy, but there is also "<< 2" operation so the result become 3 * 2^2 => 12

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved like this:

```
echo (($c || $b) << (2 * $a)) | $a;
```

and this is just some output from my test:

```
php > $a = (1 << 0);
php > echo $a;
1

php > $b = (1 << $a);
php > echo $b;
2

php > $c = (1 << $b);
php > echo $c;
4

php > echo ($c || $b);
1

php > echo ($c || $b) << 2 * $a | $a;
5

php > echo (($c || $b) << (2 * $a)) | $a;
5
```